# Password reset showing 500 error in Open edX

Tags: django, edx, openedx

I've problem in my Open edX instance when tried to reset user password. it show 500 error server.

the log is

```
Nov  9 02:16:59 ip-172-31-6-86 [service_variant=lms][openedx.core.djangoapps.user_api.helpers][env:sandbox] ERROR [ip-172-31-6-86  2138] [helpers.py:75] - An unexpected error occurred when calling 'request_password_change' with arguments '(u'ariestiyansyah.rizky@gmail.com', 'xxx.org', True)' and keyword arguments '{}': ValueError('incomplete format',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/user_api/helpers.py", line 46, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/user_api/accounts/api.py", line 403, in request_password_change
    use_https=is_secure
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/student/forms.py", line 78, in save
    email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 171, in render_to_string
    return t.render(Context(dictionary))
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 31, in render
    output = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/i18n.py", line 151, in render
    result = result % data
ValueError: incomplete format
Nov  9 02:16:59 ip-172-31-6-86 [service_variant=lms][root][env:sandbox] ERROR [ip-172-31-6-86  2138] [exceptions.py:9] - Uncaught exception from <class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 109, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 41, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/student_account/views.py", line 153, in password_change_request_handler
    request_password_change(email, request.get_host(), request.is_secure())
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/user_api/helpers.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    raise api_error(msg)
UserAPIInternalError: An unexpected error occurred when calling 'request_password_change' with arguments '(u'ariestiyansyah.rizky@gmail.com', 'xxx.org', True)' and keyword arguments '{}': ValueError('incomplete format',)
Nov  9 02:16:59 ip-172-31-6-86 [service_variant=lms][django.request][env:sandbox] ERROR [ip-172-31-6-86  2138] [base.py:213] - Internal Server Error: /account/password
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 109, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 41, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/student_account/views.py", line 153, in password_change_request_handler
    request_password_change(email, request.get_host(), request.is_secure())
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/user_api/helpers.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    raise api_error(msg)
UserAPIInternalError: An unexpected error occurred when calling 'request_password_change' with arguments '(u'ariestiyansyah.rizky@gmail.com', 'xxx.org', True)' and keyword arguments '{}': ValueError('incomplete format',)
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? thank you so much

Comment: The views is here https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/master/lms/djangoapps/student_account/views.py

Comment: this error is a python `ValueError`. try debugging this file `/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/i18n.py` . check the value of `result` and `data`.

Answer (score 0):

This error caused by missing translation, explore and fix the translation.